# regular expression to match the same character being typed with different style

Tags: regex, styles, arabic

I'm looking for a simple regular expression to match the same character being typed with different style, like : احمد - أحمد إحمد - آحمد

the word has a char that could be typed in different form.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What language or tool are you using ?

Comment: enumerate the unicode code points for the variations of a character in your regex. if at least one of the representations consist of sequences of charactres, use the alternation operator (`|`) to include said variations. the specification of unicode code points depend on the tool you are using, common idioms are `\u<code point as 4 hex digits>` and `\x{<code point as 1-4 hex digits>}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression to match: `احمد - أحمد إحمد - آحمد`

```
/[\x{627}\x{625}\x{623}\x{622}]\x{062D}\x{0645}\x{062F}/u
```

I assumed you are using PCRE flavor, if you are using a different flavor then you should look how to specify Unicode code points using your flavor and what modifiers you need to pass the regular expression engine so it can deal with Unicode.

**[Regex 101 Demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/nI1eB2)**

Comment: Thank you, I think this will be the best

Comment: @FabriGadAhmed I this has worked for you then please accept the answer.

Comment: if you please Sniffer, How I can get the unicode for any character in PHP,but not ORD('$str');

Comment: @FabriGadAhmed Sorry I don't work with PHP so I don't know, thank your for accepting the answer.

Comment: Could you please visit this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592428/mysql-query-with-regex-unicode